# Correct Procedure for mysqlConnect

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am new to php syntax and am looking for advice on creating the most acceptable or correct code. I focus on front end design, but I like to make sure my code is proper. I am in a digital media program, my instructor has given us this code for connecting to our MYSQL databases.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")or die("Cannot Connect to DB");
mysql_select_db("Example")or die("cannot select the DB Example ");
?>
```

However when I look at connect scripts online they set the **mysql_connect** function as a variable lets say **$connect** and run an **if statement** stating; if not $connect produce error, and the same for **mysql_select_db**. They also close the script with mysql_close($connect); like below

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$connect)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("Example", $connect);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Is either one better? What problems can I have if I dont close the connect with mysql_close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regarding using an `if` instead of an `or`, it doesn't matter. The `or` short-circuits, so if the connection worked, `die(...)` won't be executed. Using either is a matter of preference. If you want to use the `or` version while keeping the result of the `mysql_connect()` call, simply assign the whole expression to a variable:

   ```
   $connection = mysql_connect(...) or die('Connection failed.');
   ```
2. `mysql_close()` should be used after you're done with all your database communication.

Comment: Thanks Max, what resource would you recommend for php development, other than the php manual? If you do at all.

Answer (score 1):

The other `mysql_*()` functions will use the connection created by the latest call to `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_pconnect()`. If for some reason you want more than one connection, trusting the implicit connection object in this manner will fail. Better is to store the connection object yourself and passing it in wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Also before starting to work with databases, you should be aware that mysql is not secure anymore and is deprecated, you should use mysqli. You can use it also as object oriented language.
more details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
example :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```